# What happens if 2 processes on the same machine pull the same Docker image in parallel?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I had 2 docker run commands trying to run the same image on a VM and both of them pulled the layers separately and run successfully.

Can I rely on this behavior all the time? I am curious about this more in regards to the schedulers/orchestrators.

Comment: Can you be a bit more accurate ? Did they run on the same ISO and modifying the content when modifying datas or did they runned a copy of that image on their own ? Also this isn't a code problem so it might be better on SuperUser.SE

Comment: This is natural manner how Kubernetes works. All containers runs in a separate space.
Moreover, you can realize, that is the way how High Availability works.